# how to create test strategy for additional functionalities which are not mentioned in requirement?

Tags: testing, regression-testing, testing-strategies

Can anyone please explain how to create test strategy for those functionalities which are additionally added in our application & that is not mentioned in requirement doc.

For example - there is one functionality of button click that on double-click that button will active & another button will active on 3-clicks, On managing such functionality developer missed, buttons are now working with 5-clicks also.

So should we plan any proper test strategy to find these types of additional test cases? If yes, then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.